# Krull-Schmidt-Remak for vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I'm reading Nori's paper *The fundamental group scheme*, and I have some problems in certain passages of the proofs. This one is from chapter 1, 2.3.

Let $X$ be a complete connected reduced $k$-scheme. We have that $\operatorname{H}^0(X, \operatorname{end}V)$ is of finite dimension for all finite vector bundles $V$, and Nori states that this implies that Krull-Schmidt-Remak holds: for all finite vector bundles there is a unique decomposition (up to reorder blah blah blah...) in a direct sum of indecomposable subbundles ($V$ is indecomposable if $V=V_1\oplus V_2\Rightarrow V=V_1\vee V=V_2$). Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future readers, I answer to this old question of mine. The proof can be found in Atiyah's paper *On the Krull-Schmidt theorem with application to sheaves*.

Answer (score 0):

If $H^0(X, End V)$ is f.d., then it is a f.d. $k$-algebra, and so we find a maximal decomposition of the identity as a sum of orthogonal idempotents,
say $1 = \sum_i e_i.$    (Here maximal means that we can't refine this further.)
This gives the corresonding decomposition of $V$.  (The summand $V_i$ of $V$
is the image of the idempotent $e_i$.)

Comment: I only know this decomposition in the abelian case. Can you give reference? Thanks

Comment: @GiulioBresciani: Dear Giulio, No, although I would look in some standard reference on non-commutative rings (e.g. Farb and Dennis?).  The $e_i$ are not going to necessarily be central (or uniquely determined), because e.g. if you took  $V \oplus V$ for some indecomposable (or even irreducible) V then there will be lots of choices of decomposition (all of the form $V \oplus V$, but the actual choice of the summands are not canonical).  So first one has to decompose $1$ into a maximal sum of central orthogonal idempotents (this is unique), and then further refine this.  How is Krull--Schmidt ..

Comment: ... --Remak usually proved?  I would think that the proof can just be adapted to this context.  (Somehow the endomorphism ring being an Artinian ring should probably be the key underlying point, and that is what finite dimensionality of the $H^0$ is giving.)  Regards,

Comment: So, once realized that decompositions of the identity correspond to decompositions of the bundle, I have two problems: showing that the decomposition of the identity in central, orthogonal idempotents is unique and showing that the refinement gives isomorphic components. Everything else is absolutely straightforward. Do you know a proof of uniqueness? And for the second problem? Sorry for asking so much, but now what I have is only a reformulation of the problem in terms of idempotents, and I don't really know where to search in the 200 pages of Farb and Dennis.

Comment: For the standard proof of Krull-Schmidt-Remak, I don't know, it's the first time I meet this theorem. Anyway, I'll search it.